# Generate dump file/report when low virtual memory occurs

Tags: windows-10, memory, virtual-memory

I'm currently investigating an issue that we're having with low virtual memory on Windows 10 IoT Enterprise and I'm trying to track down the process that is causing it.

There's an app that's running on the machine constantly and the problem usually happens during the night when no one is around. The data that is present in Windows Event 2004 (`Microsoft-Windows-Resource-Exhaustion-Detector`, *Events related to exhaustion of system commit limit (virtual memory)*) does not show enough data (e.g. combined values of memory used for all listed processes amount to 2GB, while the used amount is 7.6GB which doesn't help me address the issue). I'm looking for a way to generate a memory minidump or report with all the data when that error happens. Is there something in Windows that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Either run a PerfMon data collection task continuously in background, or trigger such a task on event 2004. Or both!

You don't need a minidump (and much of the data you want would be tedious to dig out of one, anyway).